# how to open url which starts with www, window.open, without considering current location

Tags: performance

I want to open an url say "www.abc.com" by window.open method. When I try that, current window's location gets added in the beginning. So my new window contains this entire url ( + "www.abc.com") which is wrong. How can I open just "www.abc.com"?

Comment: You need to add protocol (http:// , https://)

Answer (score 0):

Add with http or https like 'http://www.abc.com'